# How to make my executable file appear outside of repository

Tags: c++, linux, git, g++

I've been doing some simple programs from a linux course. One of the tasks requires me to prevent the main executable file from being added to my git repository(when compiled), where all the source files and headers are located. I've been looking around the internet for quite a while, but I can't find any way to solve it.

Comment: You may want to know how to make `git ignore` a list of files?

Comment: @GemTaylor, I didn't know there was such a thing, I know what to do now, thank you! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+executable+file

Comment: Sometimes it is a case of searching for the right words :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's often tough for me to find appropriate words since my english is rather lacking